# Partially keeping the placeholder in UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am trying to achieve below image:

[image]

As you can see in the image, when a user types a number into the textfield, the other digits of the number still stand as a placeholder. (000 000 0000)

To do that, I placed a UILabel inside of the UITextField.

```
var placeHolderLabelString = "___ ___ ____"
var placeholderLabel = UILabel()
placeholderLabel.text = placeHolderLabelString
placeholderLabel.sizeToFit()
numberInputView.addSubview(placeholderLabel)
placeholderLabel.textColor = .gray
placeholderLabel.font = numberInputView.font
```

I want to delete each underscore when a user types a digit into the textfield. I have tried the below code:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    let rnd = Range(range, in: placeHolderLabelString)!
    placeHolderLabelString = placeHolderLabelString.replacingCharacters(in: rnd, with: " ")
    placeholderLabel.text = placeHolderLabelString

    return true
}
```

But this doesn't work. It adds a space char to the beginning of the `placeHolderLabelString`, not replacing it. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The range passed to `shouldChangeCharacters` refers to a range of the text field's text, before the change. When you normally insert text using the keyboard, the range has a length of 0, and `replacementString` is the character that you are trying to insert. The idea is that you are replacing an empty range of the text, with the new character, hence "inserting" that character.

As a result, doing a replacement of that same range with `" "` to the placeholder string, will insert a space into the placeholder string.

Rather than using the given range on the placeholder string, you should use it on the text field's text. That is what the range *means* anyway.

You can compute the new text of the text field, after the insertion, by doing:

```
let newText = (textField.text! as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
```

Then, replace the first `newText.count` characters of the placeholder string with spaces. Set this as the new text of the placeholder label.

```
// note that I changed this to a let, because I do not change the placeholder string
let placeHolderLabelString = "___ ___ ___"

func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    let newText = (textField.text! as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)

    // do not allow more text than the placeholder
    if newText.count > placeHolderLabelString.count {
        return false
    }
    
    let startIndex = placeHolderLabelString.startIndex
    let replaceableRange = startIndex..<placeHolderLabelString.index(startIndex, offsetBy: newText.count)
    let newPlaceholder = placeHolderLabelString.replacingCharacters(
        in: replaceableRange, with: String(repeating: " ", count: newText.count)
    )
    placeholderLabel.text = newPlaceholder
    return true
}
```

---

From the looks of it, you also want to automatically add spaces in some places.

To do that, you need to set `textField.text`:

```
// after the newText.count > placeHolderLabelString.count check
let spacesRemoved = newText.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
textField.text = formatPhoneNumber(spacesRemoved)
```

where `formatPhoneNumber` is a method that inserts spaces appropriately. Its implementation is left as an exercise for the reader.

Then, the rest of the code should replace the first `textField.text!.count` characters of `placeHolderLabelString`, rather than `newText.count`. Because `newText` is now no longer the text in the text field.

```
let startIndex = placeHolderLabelString.startIndex

// note that I'm using textField.text instead of newText here,
// because *that* is actually the text of the text field now
let replaceableRange = startIndex..<placeHolderLabelString.index(startIndex, offsetBy: textField.text!.count)
let newPlaceholder = placeHolderLabelString.replacingCharacters(
    in: replaceableRange, with: String(repeating: " ", count: newText.count)
)
placeholderLabel.text = newPlaceholder

// the text field's text should not change, because we set it programmatically to the desired value already.
return false
```

Comment: Wow, this is an amazing explanation. Thank you very much :)

Comment: FYI - the placeholder needs 4 underscores in the 3rd group, not 3. And this all assumes you only want to support US/Canadian phone numbers. `shouldChangeCharactersIn` also needs to ensure only digits are entered. Those pesky users might try to paste in all kinds of random text.

Comment: @HangarRash You’re right. I misread the placeholder, thinking there are only 9 digits. Ensuring only digits are entered is left as an exercise for the reader :). There are lots of posts regarding that already, and I felt like my answer is getting long. OP could have disabled paste for all we know.